# Blank Squares instead of Font Awesome

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, fonts, favicons

I am using a Magento 1.9.1 installation with Ultimo Theme. It is running two websites at the same time. This has been working for two years.

Recently, I decided to create a whole new website on the same installation. Unfortunately, all special characters and icons appear as blank squares (similar to     ❏) on the new website. I think these characters and icons are provided by Font Awesome.

While the new website looks broken this way, the two old ones don't have the error.

Is there anything I have done wrong to get this result? Is there any quick solution for that?

If not, is there any way to copy entirely a website into another website to avoid the problem?

Thanks.

Cg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the secure and unsecure URL to a different one and the squares were replaced by the right images :)